# How to print a file from a location directly without any pop

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to print a file from a location with out any pop up or windows
The code I use will show a window and need to confirm print. I don't want to see confirm window.

```
                ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                info.Verb = "print";
                info.FileName = @"c:\filename";
                info.CreateNoWindow = true;
                info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

                Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo = info;
                p.Start();
```

Comment: Usually you want to show a print dialog to the user. What if the user wants to print to PDF? What if they want it to a different printer than the default printer? There are ways to do this, but not with the "print" verb... at least not that I know of. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the Microsoft documentation. You will need to know which printer is the default, and if there is no default or no printer is installed then show the user the standard printer dialog.

This may help to get you started:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.installedprinters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.isdefaultprinter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1